# I'm trying to Modify css of my website template but I can't find file's location

Tags: html, css, wordpress, location, firebug

I use Firebug to modify my css template, but where I need to make changes it only shows my website's name plus a number ("rastmard.com #16"). Therefore I can't find the location of the file in question to save my changes. 
*So my question is; as you can see in the picture, where is the

> .chatbro_message css file 
>   *

[image: Screenshot of Firebug showing "rastmard.com #16" as CSS file]

P.S: I am using WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is being generated by your wordpress plugin and included directly into your page. That's why it doesn't show a CSS file location.

You can customize the generated css by going into the plugin editor and editing the php file.

In your case it would be located at --  http://rastmard.com/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php

[image]

In the `chatbro.php` file you'll find the following which you can tweak to your needs.

```
function set_default_settings () {
    $o = get_option('chatbro_options');
    $o['chatPath'] = 'tg/208397015/Ask your own question';
    $o['allowSendMessages'] = 'on';
    $o['chatHeaderBackgroundColor'] = '#2D3341';
    $o['showGuests'] = 'on';
    $o['showSystemMessage'] = 'on';
    $o['chatHeaderTextColor'] = '#FFFFFF';
    $o['chatBodyBackgroundColor'] = '#F7F8FC';
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I found this file before but what I need (.chatbro_message) is not in here. I can just tweak background colors and few other things from this file.

Answer (score 0):

This is [answered in Firebug's FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq#What_does_the_number_after_the_file_name_inside_the_Style_side_panel_mean):

> Q: What does the number after the file name inside the Style side
>   panel mean?
>
> Source links with a number behind them (`#2`, `#3`, ...) enumerate the internal stylesheets defined via `<style>` tags inside the page.
>
> For external CSS files the number sign means that the same file is included several times.

[A very similar description](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel#Source_Links) can be found in Firebug's wiki.

WordPress plugins often include their CSS style sheets directly within the HTML of your page instead of including it via an external file. That's why you see the name of your website as source link. The number indicates that it's the 16th style sheet embedded in your HTML.

Comment: so where these stylesheets are stored?

Comment: I've never tried this WordPress plugin, but looking at the [code of Chatbro](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/chatbro/trunk/chatbro.php) I cannot find the related CSS classes, only code for an AJAX request. So, I assume the HTML and CSS is loaded dynamically through the XMLHttpRequest.